# Sequence of real numbers which minimizes expected encoding error at any (data) rate?

Tags: probability, statistics, soft-question, nonlinear-optimization, information-theory

Let us assume that I have a continuous probability distribution with density function $x\to p(x)$ that is $1$ dimensional, monomodal and approximately symmetric.

We furthermore have a ternary tree of decisions. Every node $T_{i}$ of the ternary tree represents a situation where we need to decide $c_i$ :

$\begin{array}{rll}
-1. &\text{Sub a real number }& x_{i+1} = x_i - r_i\\
0. &\text{Nothing changes}\\
1. &\text{Add a real number} &x_{i+1} = x_i + r_i
\end{array}$

How can I decide the sequence (or vector if $N$ finite) ${\bf r} = [r_0,r_1,\cdots,r_N]^T$ so that the expected error $$ \left\|x_{true} - \left(x_0+\sum_{i}^N c_i\cdot r_i\right)\right\|$$
is minimized?

---

**Own work:** I have guessed that a reasonable starting point $x_0$ is one of the common mean values, for example arithmetic mean $$x_0 = E[p] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \xi p(\xi)d\xi$$

or median

$$x_0\,\, s.t.\, \int_{-\infty}^{x_0} p(\xi)d\xi= \frac 1 2$$
For an approximate symmetric distribution these should be the same.

Comment: Very interesting. Just a notation thing - it might be more convenient to define $c_i$ to take values $-1, 0, 1,$ so $x_{i+1} = x_i + c_i r_i$ (this avoids the $2-$ which feels a little awkward). Also, the initial guess should probably depend on the metric you're using. If the norm is $L_2,$ then mean seems a good idea, if it is $L_1,$ then the median.

Comment: Have you thought about a dynamic programming approach? Essentially, with $r_1, \dots, r_{N-1}$ in hand, figuring out $r_N$ seems possible (if a little messy). Also, it might be easier to explicitly assume symmetry as a first step. And since there's a distance involved, Bellman's principle should hold. This should go through as long as optimal $c_i$ can be chosen greedily, which might need some property like the $r_i$ being decreasing. (I'm very unsure, though)

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I personally don't like dynamic programming so much, but I will not downvote any answer which would contain it.